# Bundle install fails due to nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, nokogiri

When I run `bundle install` in my Rails 4 application I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using `rvm` and when I run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` it works well. Moreover, when I run `gem list` I see nokogiri 1.6.1 installed, it's just that `bundle install` in my app does not work.

By the way, it's happening only when I add the `impressionist` gem to my Gemfile, but I guess it's just a dependency.

More info: I have followed, just in case, the instructions [here](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html), and everything worked well.

Any ideas? TIA

---

**EDIT 1**: The full error is:

```
Installing nokogiri (1.6.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/sonxurxo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/sonxurxo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby: invalid option -P  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sonxurxo/Documents/workspace/Smart Promo/RubyOnRails/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sonxurxo/Documents/workspace/Smart Promo/RubyOnRails/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

**EDIT 2**: I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks, with XCode and developer tools successfully installed

---

**EDIT 3**: My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'authlogic'

gem 'acl9'

gem 'recaptcha'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'omniauth-twitter'

gem "paperclip", ">= 3.4.1"

gem 'kaminari'

gem 'activerecord-session_store'

gem 'rpush'

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'twitter'

gem 'gmaps4rails'

gem 'gon'

gem 'flexslider'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"

gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"

gem 'gettext_i18n_rails'

gem 'gettext', '>=3.0.2', :require => false, :group => :development

gem 'thinking-sphinx'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

gem 'daemons'

gem 'ts-delayed-delta', '~> 2.0.0', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'

gem 'geocoder'

gem 'i18n'

gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'batch_translations'

gem 'countries'
gem 'country_select'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'impressionist'
```

---

**EDIT 4**: Output for `gem list nokogiri`:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.6.1, 1.5.9)
```

Comment: please post full error

Comment: did you install all requrie library libxml , libxslt?

Comment: @RajarshiDas yes, I say it in the question, I followed the instructions in http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html. I'm on Mac OS Mavericks (I'll add this info to the question)

Comment: ooh hooo please post your `Gemfile` as well or check that `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.1'`

Comment: @RajarshiDas posted. BTW, I'm re-checking the installation of nokogiri following (again) the instructions in the page, just in case I made a typo or something...

Comment: @RajarshiDas It's probably a misconception by myself, but: I have nokogiri 1.6.1 in my gemset (checked through 'gem list' command), doesn't that mean that it should be straightforward to use it in any project? I mean, it's already installed...

Comment: `gem list nokogiri` ?

Comment: one more thing I want to tell you `impressionist` is dependence on `nokogiri` with `1.5` version

Comment: But bundle install tries to install 1.6.1. Why?

Comment: @RajarshiDas would you like to discuss it in this chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50267/nokogiri-issue?tab=general

Comment: please in `Gemfile` lock it `1.5` in Gemfile `gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.1'` and bundle install

Comment: Exactly same result :(

Comment: I still don't understand why 'gem install nokogiri' works but 'bundle install' fails

Comment: you have to installed `nokogiri version = 1.5.1` it will resolve this

Comment: I successfully installed it, but it still fails. Maybe it has something to do with rvm, I don't know why installing the gem with 'gem install' works but bundle install fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I solved this.

I say *think* because it seems to be related with a misconfiguration concerning `rvm` and `bundler`.

`bundler` was installing my gems in vendor/bundle, and not using those from the `rvm` gemset. What I did was to tell `bundler` to use those gems from `rvm`, and then, since `nokogiri` was already installed, it worked.

Thank everyone for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Impressionist has the following dependency:

```
s.add_dependency 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5'
```

Do you need the latest version of nokogiri or can you live with this version as well?

Answer (score 0):

With 'bundle install --deployment' it won't work if you are below a directory with spaces in its name. Replacing the spaces with underscores fixed a similar problem for me. See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3020